# Index and Range don't behave like a Span<T>-object?

Tags: c#, indexing, range

When you use BinaryPrimitive methods in combination with the new Range/Index feature of C# 8, I encountered that an index/ranged slice of an array can still be used in BinaryPrimitives, but won't propagate this change to the original array.

So the main question would be, if the index/range operations actually create something like a failsafe-copy of the sliced part, then what exactly are the benefits of using them beside the syntax sugar? And if there are no other benefits than that, why don't those 2 operations behave like a `Span<T>`?

```cs
var data= new byte[10];
BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32LittleEndian(data[0..4], 4);
```

and

```cs
var data= new byte[10];
BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32LittleEndian(new Span<byte>(data,0,4), 4);
```

I actually expected the first snippet to propagate the changes to the original array, since I expected it to be a slice based on the source array, just like a Span.

Comment: because that's how C# makers invented this

Comment: Shouldn't the first code snippet be `data[0..4]` instead of `byte[0..4]`?

Comment: You're looking for `data.AsSpan(0..4)`. (And the ability to pass ranges and slices as instances is a little more than "syntactic sugar".)

Comment: @RandRandom That's right, I edited it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That indeed sounds like a good method in the future. I will remember it.

Comment: FWIW, this was [discussed here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2018/LDM-2018-12-03.md#return-values-of-range-indexers). Ease of use for everyone who isn't using `Span` was considered more important than going for performance. (Using a magic array that aliases the original one was not discussed -- while possible in theory, that would require big changes on the runtime level, unlike the current implementation.) As all `Span`s are innately sliceable (i.e. `"Hello, world!".AsSpan()[0..5]`, the overhead for people who want a `Span`/`ReadOnlySpan` is minimal.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - IMHO your comment should be an answer